# What triggers cross-domain violation when AJAX request?

Tags: ajax, security, browser, cors

I was asked a question below and cannot find the answer. I looked up similar posts, but many posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)) ended up talking about cross-origin, not cross-domain. What is the answer to the below question?

Q: Assume you are working on a webpage at http://example.com/path/to/foo.html.
if you were to send an AJAX request to the following URLs, which one would NOT trigger a cross-domain violation?

A: `http://example.com/bar`

B: `https://example.com/path/to/bar.html`

C: `https://example.com:80/bar`

D: `http://www.example.com/bar`

E: `C and D`

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:
Originally, I came across a website saying `there is a 'Cross-domain violation' which is different from 'CORS' since 'origin' and 'domain' points different part.` That's why I have been looking for the definition of `'cross-domain violation'`. But it was actually the same as 'same-origin policy', as the answer below shows.

Comment: What are you referring to by "cross-domain violation"? Are you asking which cross-origin requests trigger a preflight request? If so, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests

Comment: This question is specifically asking 'cross-domain violation'.

Comment: And I'm asking what you mean by that term. It's not clear to me.

Comment: Me neither. That's why I am asking here.

Comment: Where did you come across the term in the first place?

Comment: Poor wording on their part, esp. if you couldn't ask for clarification. That term isn't standard, but I'm guessing it refers to a request that would violate the Same-Origin Policy, which can be selectively relaxed using CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to this:

> A resource is cross-origin when it's located at a different
> (sub)domain, protocol, or port!

You should also use `exact match host` so `http://www.example.com/bar` doesn't work out.

Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules) to see more examples.

You should not get CORS in the `A` option.

And also [this](https://blog.learncodeonline.in/web-security-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors) article fully describing CORS.

Comment: "A resource is cross-origin when it's located at a different (sub)domain, protocol, or port!"
Where does this quote come from? I found that if 'cross origin' violation, it restricts http and https, so answer can be A and D. But the 'cross domain' restriction doesn't care...And I am still confused what the 'cross-domain violation' then...Also, there should be only 1 answer.

Comment: @Chi Thanks, I update the answer. the quote is ok and works well as Wikipedia said: "{scheme, host, port}" the schema is the protocol. take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules) which may be helpfull.

Comment: Thank you! This link is the clearest I've ever seen!